# Prove certain polynomials are irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, rational-numbers

I've been solving some problems preparing for my final exam of abstract algebra, and I want to know if my solution to this problem is correct, and ask some questions related to it too. The problem is:

> Prove that the following polynomials are irreducible in
> $\mathbb{Q}[X]$:
>
> (a) $\frac{2}{9}X^5 + \frac{5}{3}X^4+X^3+\frac{1}{3}$
>
> (b) $2X^5-6X^3+9X^2-15$
>
> (c) $X^3+6X^2+17+3$
>
> (d) $X^4+4X^3+6X^2+2X+1$

This is the work I've done, tell me if there's anything wrong:

**(a)** For this one, I first multiply the polynomial by $9$, because $9\in\mathbb{Q}^\times$ and that means the result of the multiplication does not change the condition of being irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. So the result of the multiplication is the polynomial $2X^5+15X^4+3X^3+3$, and I can use Eisenstein's criterion with $p=3$ to prove it's irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

**(b)** For this one, just Eisenstein's criterion with $p=3$ and it's concluded it's irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

**(c)** For this one, I started looking for possible roots in $\mathbb{Q}$. Since it's coefficients are all positive, the leading coefficient is $1$ and the independent coefficient is $3$, the only possible roots in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ are $-1$ and $-3$. I evaluate the polynomial in both and see that it does not turn into $0$, so I conclude that this polynomial has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, and then I conclude it's irreducible beacuse it's degree is $3$.

**(d)** For this last one, I use the fact that, given $p(X)$ irreducible, the map that turns $p(X)$ into $p(X+a)$ is homomorphism (hence it does not change the condition of being irreducible), so I calculate $p(X+1)$ and get as result $X^4+8X^3+24X^2+30X+14$, which I know is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ by Eisenstein's criterion with $p=2$.

So, given this work, the questions I have are:

- Are my solutions correct?
- In part (d), where I evaluated the polynomial in $(X+1)$, I did it randomly. I don't know how can I "decide the right $(X+a)$ to choose". Is there any tip or guide that may let me guess what's the right $(X+a)$ to then use Eisenstein's criterion?
- I get confused with the "divisibility" concept in $\mathbb{Q}$. In integers its clear that, for example, $3$ divides $15$, but does $3$ divide $\frac{15}{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$? Or does $3$ divide $\frac{1}{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$? I'm not sure how this concept is defined in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your solutions look correct to me. In fact, if I were an instructor , gave those questions in an exam and you submitted that answer, I'd be delighted! +1

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you very much!

Comment: Choosing Eisenstein translates has to do with algebraic number theoretic properties of integers (ramification).

Comment: Divisibility in $\mathbb Q$ (or any field) is not very interesting, every non-zero element is a unit.

Comment: Parts (a.) and (b.)  are completely correct. On part (c.), the Rational Roots Theorem implies that the possible roots are $\pm 3$ and $\pm 1.$ (But I see now that all of the coefficients are positive, so you don't need to check the positive terms.) Last, for your question of divisibility in $\mathbb Q,$ all of the nonzero elements are units, hence any two nonzero elements divide each other, e.g., $3 \cdot \frac 1 6 = \frac 1 2,$ hence $3$ divides $\frac 1 2.$

Comment: @DietrichBurde So when using Eisenstein criterion, am I considering the divisibility condition in the $\mathbb{Z}$ usual way? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Carlo Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso, Eisenstein's Criterion works with the prime ideals of a UFD $R.$ Because $\mathbb Q$ is a field, it is a UFD, but its only prime ideal is the zero ideal. So, you are really using Eisenstein's Criterion over $\mathbb Z$: if $f(x)$ is a "primitive" polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$ (i.e., the greatest common divisor of the coefficients of $f(x)$ is $\pm 1$) and $f(x)$ is $p$-Eisenstein for some prime integer $p,$ then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$ by [Gauss's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29#The_lemma_over_the_integers).

Comment: @Carlo Oh, I see. Thank you very much!